# How to execute multiples SQL in one QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this:

```
SELECT count(*) as total_chamadas from ticket WHERE userid = 'root';
SELECT count(*) as total_chamadas_tday from ticket WHERE userid = 'root' AND date(DataCriacao) = CURDATE();
```

How can I do to execute these two segments and return:

```
+----------------+---------------------+
| total_chamadas | total_chamadas_tday |
+----------------+---------------------+
|             10 |                   5 |
+----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_chamadas, SUM(date(DataCriacao) = CURDATE()) AS total_chamadas`

Comment: The gist is to combine your SELECTs and derive them all from the largest set, as Barmer shared above.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! worked very well, i followed the zcoop98 tip also :)